# SOAP UI- Automation token retrieval process not working

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, soapui

I have implemented the java script in the Automation window of SOAP UI in the Oauth Profile. But this is not working until user runs it manually. How to automatically call the script whenever my token will expired.

```
enter code here
function consent(){
document.getElementById('loginform').click();
}

if (document.getElementById('login')) {
document.getElementById('login').value = 'xxxx@xxx.com';
document.getElementById('password').value = 'xxxxx';
document.loginform.submit();
}

else if (document.getElementById('loginform')){
window.setInterval(content,100);
}
```

Comment: Which edition of soapUI are you using such as free or pro and its version please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it needs to be handled.

1. Call the service to get the token token.
2. The above response must also contains the expiry time in the headers, extract it and store in a property along with token
3. Make a normal service call which requires valid token

   - before sending request, find the current time and compare it with the property stored in step 2
   - if current time is less than expiry time, use the same token
   - else repeat the same steps

Now, the question stand is how to run random code before actually running a test step?

You should be able to execute some extra code, which is need in this case, using `setup`, `teardown` scripts of  `test case, test suite, project` etc. i.e.,

*Allow me to explain with an example.*

You are running a test case which has a step to invoke some service and it requires `token`.

Add the required code to **evaluate whether a token is to be retrieved again or reuse the existing one**. This should be part of setup script of the test case, so that always the code in setup script gets executed before running a test case. Remember that, your script will not be run if you run on test step of that test case, so make sure you run the test case.

> **Note:** 
> But, it can't be done for a test step level at the moment using SoapUI open source edition.
>
> There is feature called `Events` available in `Ready! API`, where one can have very fine control on what to be done and when. This feature is not available in Open Source edition of `SoapUI`.
>
> But for open source, an [extension](https://github.com/nmrao/soapuiExtensions) available, which I did some time ago, where that will allow some one to run some custom code for certain events like beforeStep, afterStep etc., That is tried using Groovy Script. However, you seemed to be using Javascript here. If you wish you may give a try the extension, of course, if needed.

**Update:**

As author of question request for some info, so updating the answer.

You can have a look this documentation [link](https://www.soapui.org/scripting---properties/custom-event-handlers.html) which shows how to use the `custom events` functionality of pro software to do something more when certain conditions are met on demand.

Also there is a [webinar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92WEfVJPJDQ) by SmartBear team which shows how to use events, but little lengthy in time. All uses `groovy`.

I see you using `Javascript`, is there anything that driving you to use it? or just you comfortable using it? Never mind, you should be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks Rao..I am using both the version means looking for a universal solution. Thanks for explaining this but can you please provide some more details like the script & where exactly to call.

Comment: Updated the answer with some useful resource links. I am no voice in javascript. But, will be able help if there is groovy involved, again if there is anything more specific if you have.