# SoapUI: How to pass the token variable and concat it in another test?

Tags: json, web-services, api, soapui

I'm new to API testing and I'm using SoapUI. I have some tests that need authentication and I have been able to get the SessionId using the transfer value but I ve yet to succeed in using this variable in my test. My header is "Authorisation" and value is "Token" and I would like to add the Session variable to my token value. How can I achieve it ? Maybe my concat value is wrong. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if this helps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35427172/soap-ui-automation-token-retrieval-process-not-working/35451522#35451522

Comment: Thanks Rao for the response. Does it mean I can't do it with open source version. Do i need to setup a groovy step ? As I said I have already retrieved the token...I only need to add it to other tests as variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem using groovy:

```
def sessionToken = context.expand( '${[Testcase name]#Response#$.[session variable]}' )

def accessToken = 'Token ' + sessionToken

testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("accessToken", accessToken)
```

Just change the "Testcase name" and "session variable". Add "Authorization" into your test's header with the value "${#TestCase#accessToken}"